# How to "push" my question?

Tags: support, editing, questions

:)

I posted a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115180/15717) on the main TeX-StackExchange-page a couple of weeks ago. I did not receive an answer, unfortunately, but the problem remains. Of course, my post disappeared *somewhere* into oblivion. xD

Is there a common way to bring one's posts back on the first page, if they haven't been dealt with? Like posting a comment/an answer to/in the question/thread, or simply delete it and then post it again?

I'm still kind of "green" since I created this profile not long ago and want to get sure how the things are rolling here. :)

Thank you!

Comment: Related [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/340/15717)

Comment: Also link your questoin here such that people can look at it while they are interested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Martin suggested, bounties and bumping attract attention to your question by making it more visible.  We also occasionally have drives to answer lots of the unanswered questions, so even low visibility questions get answered.

However, I guess your problem was solved because asking about it on meta attracted Scott's attention, so going out and asking people is a good strategy.

Chat probably is better than meta for attracting attention to particular questions - meta tends to be a bit "policy and how to" oriented, and chat allows a more dynamic discussion, say, about how to improve the question.  You have enough reputation to go to chat and ask people there about why they think your question is not getting an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Generally you can [place a bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) on your question, but this requires more reputation than you have now.

If you didn't got any answers now, maybe your question wasn't phrased very well or misses something else. Have another look on it and try to improve it. This will also place it on the first page again.

Comment: Since I spend a lot of time on formulating and editing my posts I don't think it was ambiguous - I made some minor changes, anyway, to get it back on top.

Is one of my proposed actions yet appropriate?
Please comment on that in your answer and I'll be happy to "accept" it. :D